# Global View in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to create a "global view" in the AppDelegate. So the view always shows no matter what controller you are on in the app. I built a cocoapod for this and here is very basic code that I have so far.

```
import UIKit

open class BetaBug: NSObject {
    public var myView = UIView()
    public override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    open func show() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50))
            myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            window.addSubview(myView)
        }
    }
}
```

And in the AppDelegate of my project I have in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
    let a = BetaBug()
    a.show()
```

Am I on the right track here? Is this possible?

Comment: Do not put *UI elements* in `AppDelegate`. Instead try putting your view in Custom `UINavigationController`. `UINavigationController` already has `NavigationBar` which shows up in every `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make seperate viewcontroller and add transparent image in background also set clear color of top view in vc. Then u can add that vc's view with addsubview of rootviewcontrller. To dismiss u can use nsnotificationcenter. I am doing exactly the same.